# C program files compiling with VIM on windows10

Tags: c, gcc, vim, compilation

Is there anything that I need to configure in order that VIM on my Win10 machine compiles my C files?
As of this moment, VIM throws me into the DOS prompt with the following:

```
[No write since last change]
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file a.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

shell returned 1

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: Well, VIM doesn't compile anything, it invokes another program to do that. It appears Vim does know where to find mingw's build tools and is using them. Are you currently running a.exe? Do you have a makefile? Is your current directory set to a location you have write access to?

Comment: I have various other IDE`s that are working fine, Yes, I have a makefile, but I am not sure of the context in which I should be seeing it. Could this vague information still invoke some help. I would appreciate it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your *_vimrc* file

```
set makeprg=gcc\ -o\ %:r\ %\ -Wall
```

Also, add the bin directory of your gcc compiler to the path.

Comment: Thanks Rishikesh...I am just starting out with VIM, could you help me further. I like to know where in the vimrc file I should add the makeprg set